# Issues with Codable Arrays and Alamofire

Tags: swift, alamofire, codable

I am attempting to submit the following request through Alamofire and I am receiving the following error:

> 2020-01-13 09:41:05.912103-0600 AFNetworkingDemo[29720:604258] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Invalid type in JSON write (__SwiftValue)'

My assumption is that it is the way I am defining the arrays within the object (I was following some of the material found here: https://benscheirman.com/2017/06/swift-json)

```
struct ProgramRequest: Codable {
    var userID: Int
    var programData: ProgramData

    var json: Constants.Json {
        return [
            "userID": userID,
            "programData": programData.json,
        ]
    }
}

struct ProgramData: Codable {
    var airhotel: [AirHotel]
    var security: [Security]

    var json: Constants.Json {
        return [
            "airhotel": airhotel,
            "security": security
        ]
    }
}

struct AirHotel: Codable {
    var id: Int
    var loyaltyNumber: String

    var json: Constants.Json {
        return [
            "id": id,
            "loyaltyNumber": loyaltyNumber
        ]
    }
}

struct Security: Codable {
    var vendorCode: String
    var loyaltyNumber: String

    var json: [String: Any] {
        return [
            "vendorCode": vendorCode,
            "loyaltyNumber": loyaltyNumber
        ]
    }
}
```

The json dictionary at each level is to render the objects appropriately for Alamofire. For a given example, if I print it out using:

```
let jsonEncoder = JSONEncoder()
jsonEncoder.outputFormatting = .prettyPrinted

let jsonData = try jsonEncoder.encode(programRequest)

if let jsonString = String(data: jsonData, encoding: .utf8) {
    print(jsonString) #1
}

print("IsValidJSON: ", JSONSerialization.isValidJSONObject(programRequest)) #2

print(programRequest.json) #3

urlRequest = try! JSONEncoding.default.encode(urlRequest, with: programRequest.json) #4 causes error
```

1 output:

```
{
  "userID" : 10021,
  "programData" : {
    "airhotel" : [],
    "security" : [
    {
        "vendorCode" : "sty",
        "loyaltyNumber" : "Loyal1"
    }
    ]
  }
}
```

2 output
    IsValidJSON:  false

3 output - I noticed the AFNetworkingDemo.Security within the output, is that what Alamofire JSONEncoding on:

```
["programData": ["security": [AFNetworkingDemo.Security(vendorCode: "sty", loyaltyNumber: "Loyal1")], "airhotel": []], "userID": 10021]
```

My question would be, what changes to I need to make in the AirHotel and Security sections of ProgramRequest in order to resolve my issues with Alamofire?

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with Alamofire. I suggest you you look into how Codable works, as you can get that working without Alamofire at all. Also, there's not Alamofire usage in the question.

Comment: The error message is being returned from Alamofire through the invocation: try! JSONEncoding.default.encode(urlRequest, with: programRequest.json).  In regards to how Codeable works, my issue is working with Codable and AlamoFire and its JSONEncoding mechanism.

Comment: Yes, if you want to use `Encodable` parameters you must either update to Alamofire 5 or write your own parameter handling in Alamofire 4.

Comment: I am currently using Alamofire 5 (5.0.0-rc.3).

Comment: Then you need to be using `JSONParameterEncoder`, not `JSONEncoding`.

Comment: Good to know, I was not aware of this change. Making the change that Luca suggested and using JSONParameterEncoder resolved my issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Step 1: Stop reinventing Codable

The json computed property is not needed and wrongly used.

Remove it.

```
struct ProgramRequest: Codable {
    var userID: Int
    var programData: ProgramData
}

struct ProgramData: Codable {
    var airhotel: [AirHotel]
    var security: [Security]
}

struct AirHotel: Codable {
    var id: Int
    var loyaltyNumber: String
}

struct Security: Codable {
    var vendorCode: String
    var loyaltyNumber: String
}
```

### Step 2: Start using Codable

Now given a `programRequest`, eg. like this

```
let programRequest = ProgramRequest(userID: 1, programData: ProgramData(airhotel: [AirHotel(id: 1, loyaltyNumber: "loyaltyNumber")], security: [Security(vendorCode: "loyaltyNumber", loyaltyNumber: "loyaltyNumber")]))
```

You can generate the correct Data value representing the JSON simply writing

```
let data = try JSONEncoder().encode(programRequest)
```

And (if you want) you can convert data intro a String

```
let json = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
```

### Output

```
Optional("{\"userID\":1,\"programData\":{\"airhotel\":[{\"id\":1,\"loyaltyNumber\":\"loyaltyNumber\"}],\"security\":[{\"vendorCode\":\"loyaltyNumber\",\"loyaltyNumber\":\"loyaltyNumber\"}]}}")
```

That's it

Comment: The issue is, Alamofire, through the statement JSONEncoding.default.encode(urlRequest, with: data) is expecting a Dictionary, ie. I get an error that states: Cannot convert value of type 'ProgramRequest' to expected argument type 'Parameters?' (aka 'Optional<Dictionary<String, Any>>'). That was the reason for the json sections at each level of the object hierarchy.